# Listing all directories in a bash arguments

Tags: bash

Let's assume I have a bash script example.sh. Running the script requires the argument which is the list of the directories. The the script works like this:

```
./example.sh "/dir/location/281/rest-of-the-location"  "/dir/location/287/rest-of-the-location"  "/dir/location/37/rest-of-the-location"  "/dir/location/3007/rest-of-the-location"
```

All the list of the directories are saved in a file called file.txt.  Is there a simple way to run the script instead putting the directories in the second quote like the above?

All the directories are saved in a file called `file.txt`

```
 file.txt
 /dir/location/281/rest-of-the-location
 /dir/location/37/rest-of-the-location
 /dir/location/3007/rest-of-the-location
 /dir/location/3127/rest-of-the-location
/dir/location/37/rest-of-the-location
/dir/location/372/rest-of-the-location
/dir/location/137/rest-of-the-location
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xargs`:

```sh
xargs ./example.sh < file.txt
```

If example.sh interacts with the user, you may need to add the `-o` option to xargs, or with GNU xargs use `xargs -a file.txt ./example.sh`

Comment: `xargs -a file.txt ./example.sh `
 this  one worked. Thanks. 

`xargs ./example.sh < file.txt` this is not showing anything 

If I use `o` option, it says
`xargs: invalid option -- 'o'`